# invert image black to white in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-image

I have a bitmap image with black and white color I just need to invert the image and display how can I convert and display image. I have inverted bitmap image in java using this code can anyone suggest me how to do this in a flutter.

```
    private Bitmap createInvertedBitmap(Bitmap src) {
        ColorMatrix colorMatrix_Inverted =
                new ColorMatrix(new float[] {
                        -1,  0,  0,  0, 255,
                        0, -1,  0,  0, 255,
                        0,  0, -1,  0, 255,
                        0,  0,  0,  1,   0});

        ColorFilter ColorFilter_Sepia = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(
                colorMatrix_Inverted);

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(src.getWidth(), src.getHeight(),
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

        Paint paint = new Paint();

        paint.setColorFilter(ColorFilter_Sepia);
        canvas.drawBitmap(src, 0, 0, paint);

        return bitmap;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now it is possible to change/invert the color via [ColorFiltered class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ColorFiltered-class.html)

You can refer to this blog for more details: https://www.burkharts.net/apps/blog/over-the-rainbow-colour-filters/

### Another solution

You can try using [ShaderMask class](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/ShaderMask-class.html), and try passing it to the corresponding `Shader`, such as `InvertColorShader`. Currently, no shader can do this as of now.

Also check out [BlendMode class](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-ui/BlendMode-class.html) to achieve your desired result.